# Are queries using related_name more performant in Django?

Tags: django, django-orm

Lets say I have the following models set up:

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    ...

class Product(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, related_name='products')
```

Now lets say we want to query all the products from the shop with `label` 'demo' whose prices are below $100. There are two ways to do this:

```
shop = Shop.objects.get(label='demo')
products = shop.products.filter(price__lte=100)
```

Or

```
shop = Shop.objects.get(label='demo')
products = Products.objects.filter(shop=shop, price__lte=100)
```

Is there a difference between these two queries? The first one is using the `related_name` property. I know foreign keys are indexed, so searching using them should be faster, but is this applicable in our first situation?

Comment: There is no difference between the queries, if you use `shop.products`, you implicitly pass a `shop=shop` filter to the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: this will result in *equivalent* queries.

We can do the test by printing the queries:

```
>>> print(shop.products.filter(price__lte=100).query)
SELECT "app_product"."id", "app_product"."shop_id", "app_product"."price" FROM "app_product" WHERE ("app_product"."shop_id" = 1 AND "app_product"."price" <= 100)
>>> print(Product.objects.filter(shop=shop, price__lte=100).query)
SELECT "app_product"."id", "app_product"."shop_id", "app_product"."price" FROM "app_product" WHERE ("app_product"."price" <= 100 AND "app_product"."shop_id" = 1)
```

except that the conditions in the `WHERE` are swapped, the two are equal. But usually this does not make any difference at the database side.

If you however are *not* interested in the `Shop` object itself, you can filter with:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(shop__label='demo', price__lte=100)
```

This will make a JOIN at the database level, and will thus retrieve the data in a single pass:

```
SELECT "app_product"."id", "app_product"."shop_id", "app_product"."price"
FROM "app_product"
INNER JOIN "app_shop" ON "app_product"."shop_id" = "app_shop"."id"
WHERE "app_product"."price" <= 100 AND "app_shop"."label" = demo
```